# How do I write a predicate for this in a single xpath?

Tags: xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I'm trying to write a function to return a value based on attributes that adhere to a certain logic.

```
if <Position isAdded="1"> exists then this is what I need.

if <Position isAdded="1"> doesn't exist, and <Position isUpdated=1> exists, that I need this element.

I never should pull <Position isDeleted=1>

If isAdded and isUpdated don't exist, then I need to get the value from 
<Position> without any attributes.
```

This is what I've tried so far
    /Root/Effective_Change/Position[not(exists(@isDeleted))][exists(@isAdded)]

get's me the isAdded element.
I can add multiple choose when and test for every attribute. I'm just 
trying to see if this can be done in a single xpath. Since there are a lot of elements in my xml, I don't want to do this for every element. Hence 
trying to build a function.
Like

```
/Root/Effective_Change/Position[if (exists(@isAdded then
     .[@isAdded]
else if exists(@isUpdated) then 
.[@isUpdated] else not(exists(@isDeleted))]
```

Sample xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <Effective_Change Sequence="1">
        <Position isUpdated="1">
            <Business_Title>Updated Product Engineer</Business_Title>
            <Worker_Type>Regular</Worker_Type>
        </Position>
        <Position isAdded="1">
            <Business_Title>Product Engineer</Business_Title>
            <Worker_Type>Regular</Worker_Type>
        </Position>
        <Position isDeleted="1">
            <Business_Title>Deleted Product Engineer</Business_Title>
            <Worker_Type>Regular</Worker_Type>
        </Position>
        <Position>
            <Business_Title>Product Engineer</Business_Title>
            <Worker_Type>Regular</Worker_Type>
        </Position>
    </Effective_Change>
</Root>
```

The actual file can have these attributes at multiple levels. for 
example:

```
<Position isUpdated="1">
    <Business_Title>Updated Product Engineer</Business_Title>
    <Worker_Type isDeleted="1">Temporary</Worker_Type>
    <Worker_Type isAdded="1">Regular</Worker_Type>
</Position>
```

I use this function to get non-deleted data

```
<xsl:function name="this:getNonDeletedElement">
    <xsl:param name="element"/>
    <xsl:variable name="nodeName">
        <xsl:value-of select="$element[1]/name()"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="exists($element/ancestor::*[name() = 'Effective_Change']//*[not(exists(@isDeleted))]/*[name() = $nodeName][not(exists(@isDeleted))])">
            <xsl:value-of select="$element/ancestor::*[name() = 'Effective_Change']//*[not(exists(@isDeleted))]/*[name() = $nodeName][not(exists(@isDeleted))]"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="''"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:function>
```

This function, however, would still return isAdded, isUpdated and non-attributed rows. In that case, if isAdded exists, I need that, if isAdded doesnt exist and isUpdated does, then I need that, else the non-attributed row.

I'm using this to check for isAdded

```
<xsl:function name="this:isElementAdded">
    <xsl:param name="element"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$element/../@isAdded or $element/@isAdded or exists($element/ancestor::*[@isAdded and name(..)='Effective_Change'])">
            <xsl:value-of select="true()"/>                                                 
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="false()"/>                        
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:function>
```

I'm wondering if there's a simpler way to doing this.

Comment: If you really want to write a function then you need to use `xsl:function` and it might help us understand what you want to achieve if you show/declare the parameter names and types of that function and the result type you want that function to have. Other than that I am struggling to understand what the issue is, you have used a lot of terminology in a confusing way, e.g. "get's me the isAdded element" although there are no elements of the name `isAdded` at all in your samples.

Comment: So the function expects one parameter named `element`, what type of elemen node do you expect to pass in? And if you pass in a single element node, why do you later one use `$element[1]`? Do you pass in a single element node or a sequence? What kind of result do you expect the function to return, another element node, a string value, a text node (as you currently do with `xsl:value-of`)?

Comment: I call it like this `<xsl:value-of select="this:getNonDeletedElement(/Root/Effective_Change/Position/Worker_Type)"/>` and `$element[1]` is to just just pass one value incase there are more than one value returned for that xpath, this is just to get the name.

Comment: What is that function `this:isElementAdded` supposed to return? An XSLT/XPath boolean value? Then it should simply do `<xsl:sequence select="$element/../@isAdded or $element/@isAdded or exists($element/ancestor::*[@isAdded and name(..)='Effective_Change'])"/>` although I would rewrite the `name(..)='Effective_Change` as `parent::Effective_Change` e.g. `<xsl:sequence select="$element/../@isAdded or $element/@isAdded or $element/ancestor::*[@isAdded and parent::Effective_Change]"/>`.

Comment: It is good practice to declare the wanted return type of a function with e.g. `xsl:function name="this:isElementAdded" as="xs:boolean"`.